# uncheck all other radio buttons in Meteor template event

Tags: javascript, jquery

This Meteor template allows the user to click a radio button but failed to un-check the other radio buttons. Is there an efficient way to do it in javascript or jQuery in conjunction with the current `click .twin-item'`event?

```
<template name="results">
  <div class="twin-group js-radioGroup" data-id={{_id}}>
    <ul class="upShift">
      {{#each display.deciders}}
        <li>
          <label class="twin-item">
            <input type="radio" value={{this.result}}>
            <span class="radio-label">{{this.label}}</span>
          </label>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
Template.results.events({
  'click .twin-item': (event) => {
    let val = event.target.value;
    if (val) {
      Meteor.call('myMethod', val);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need javascript for it. If you assign the same `name` attribute to all the radio buttons, only one radio button will be checked by default

change your code to

```
<template name="results">
  <div class="twin-group js-radioGroup" data-id={{_id}}>
    <ul class="upShift">
      {{#each display.deciders}}
        <li>
          <label class="twin-item">
            <input type="radio" name="rbtn" value={{this.result}}>
            <span class="radio-label">{{this.label}}</span>
          </label>
        </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```